# use mongoose method to insert data in schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an order schema that has two fields one is userid and another is the username. I receive userid from the API what I want is based on userid I retrieve the username from user schema and update it in the order schema. I added a method in the order schema for this purpose.

```
OrderSchema.methods.setCustomerName=function()
{
    let _id=this.userID;
    User.findOne({_id},(err,item) =>
    {
        if(item)
        {
            this.customer=item.firstName+" "+item.lastName;
        }
    })
}
```

I called this method while creating the order.

```
  const newOrder = Order({
                    products: products,
                    price: totalAmount,
                    totalAmount: totalAmount,
                    userID: userID
                })

                newOrder.setCustomerName();
```

and finally, save the new order

```
 newOrder.save((err, order) => {
                    if (order) {

                        return res.json({
                            status: true,
                            message: "Payment received"
                        })
                    } 
})
```

However, this is not working. I did not even get a blank value in the username field. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const newOrder = new Order({
                    products: products,
                    price: totalAmount,
                    totalAmount: totalAmount,
                    userID: userID
                })
```

Suggestion: Could be more cleaner if you use Async/Await instead of call back.